# Can a non-PCI Compliant Service Provider provide SAQ A-EP compliance?

Tags: pci-dss, pci-scope, e-commerce

I am trying to find clarification regarding PCI Compliance SAQ A-EP and third party hosting solutions.

In order to achieve SAQ A-EP PCI Compliance using "Hosting Company A" is it necessary for "Hosting Company A" to be a Certified PCI Compliant Service Provider?

Feel free to expand your response as necessary, but what I am hoping to find is a Yes or No answer and "why".

Answer (score 2):

**Yes,** SAQ A-EP requires your hosting provider be *validated to all applicable PCI DSS requirements*.

To quote the [SAQ A-EP](https://www.pcisecuritystandards.org/documents/SAQ_A-EP_v3.pdf) itself (emphasis mine):

> SAQ A-EP merchants confirm that, for this payment channel:
>
> ...
>
> - **If merchant website is hosted by a third-party provider, the provider is validated to all applicable PCI DSS requirements** (e.g.,
>     including PCI DSS Appendix A if the provider is a shared hosting
>     provider);
> - All elements of payment pages that are delivered to the consumer’s browser originate from either the merchant’s website or a PCI DSS
>     compliant service provider(s);